# ReadableStream halts halfway while downloading a large file on Firefox 78.2

Tags: javascript, firefox, browser, whatwg-streams-api

I am using the ReadableStream API to stream blocks of a large CSV file of 128 MB with more than 300,000 rows of data. I have followed the [MDN ReadableStream documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Streams_API/Using_readable_streams#Creating_your_own_custom_readable_stream) to create a ReadableStream and enqueue chunks, but somehow the ReadableStream stops reading halfway. It ends up reading only 40,000 rows. My code:

```js
  const reader = file.stream().getReader();

  reader.read().then(function processText({ done, value}) {
    if (done) {
      console.log('done');
      return;
    }

    // console.log('streaming');
    console.log(value);

    return reader.read().then(processText);
  });
```

- On Chrome and Edge, the file loads correctly: [image]
- On Firefox, it just hangs halfway: [image]

Comment: How big is the initial file? 128MB? And where does it come from?

Comment: Yes it's 128 MB, and it comes from an `<input type='file'/>` element.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xen0fpcb/1/ Can't repro on my FF78 on macOS with 16GB of RAM.

Comment: I can't reproduce it either using the jsfiddle that you wrote. Do you think running this within Vue/React is causing an issue?

Comment: I don't know. Definitely something between this minimal example and what you have is causing the issue. I invite you to either remove things from your current status, or add from my jsfiddle until you find out what it is.

Comment: I'll give it a shot and see how it goes. Thanks a lot for the help.